# Is there a symbol that represents the current address in GNU GAS assembly?

Tags: assembly, gnu, gnu-assembler, memory-address

I am curious to know is there any special GAS syntax to achieve the same like in NASM example:

```
SECTION .data       

    msg:    db "Hello World",10,0  ; the 0-terminated string.
    len:    equ $-msg              ; "$" means current address.
```

Especially I'm interested in the symbol `$` representing the current address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a useful comparison between gas and NASM here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html

See in particular this part, which I think addresses your question:

---

Listing 2 also introduces the concept of a location counter (line 6). NASM provides a special variable (the $ and $$ variables) to manipulate the location counter. In GAS, there is no method to manipulate the location counter and you have to use labels to calculate the next storage location (data, instruction, etc.).
For example, to calculate the length of a string, you would use the following idiom in NASM:

```
prompt_str db 'Enter your name: '
STR_SIZE equ $ - prompt_str     ; $ is the location counter
```

The $ gives the current value of the location counter, and subtracting the value of the label (all variable names are labels) from this location counter gives the number of bytes present between the declaration of the label and the current location. The equ directive is used to set the value of the variable STR_SIZE to the expression following it. A similar idiom in GAS looks like this:

```
prompt_str:
     .ascii "Enter Your Name: "

pstr_end:
     .set STR_SIZE, pstr_end - prompt_str
```

The end label (pstr_end) gives the next location address, and subtracting the starting label address gives the size. Also note the use of .set to initialize the value of the variable STR_SIZE to the expression following the comma. A corresponding .equ can also be used. There is no alternative to GAS's set directive in NASM.

---

Comment: `.` in GAS is (almost?) exactly like `$` in NASM, and would work for this example.

Answer (score 29):

Excerpt from `info as` (GNU Binutils 2.21.90), or online in the GAS manual: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.html

> #### 5.4 The Special Dot Symbol
>
> The special symbol `.` refers to the current address that `as` is
> assembling into.  Thus, the expression `melvin: .long .` defines
> `melvin` to contain its own address.
>
> Assigning a value to `.` is treated the same as a `.org` directive.
> Thus, the expression `.=.+4` is the same as saying `.space 4`.

```
msg:    .ascii "Hello World!\n"       # not zero-terminated, use .asciz for that
msglen = . - msg                      # A .equ directive would be equivalent
```

This is a GAS version of the same [idiom used in NASM (`len equ $ - symbol`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) to get the assembler to calculate the length of something for you.

Answer (score 5):

**Sample usages of `.`**

Minimal explicit example:

```
x: .long .
mov x, %eax
mov $x, %ebx
/* eax == ebx */
```

Common combo for string lengths:

```
s: .ascii "abcd"
s_len = . - s
mov $s_len, %eax
/* eax == 4 */
```

`s_len =` syntax explained at [Is there a difference between equals sign assignment "x = 1" and ".equ x, 1" or ".set x, 1" in GNU Gas assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175248/is-there-a-difference-between-equals-sign-assignment-x-1-and-equ-x-1-or)

This can be used concretely for example in a [minimal runnable x86 Linux freestanding example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/b1bfd46efebabcba4f1ab1cbddf99611550e2dc2/userland/arch/x86_64/freestanding/linux/hello.S#L22).

Infinite loop:

```
jmp .
```